# Irfanview How can I change the green font used to view .txt files?

Tags: fonts, colors, irfanview

Irfanview How can I change the green font used to view .txt files?

Using v4.6 on Win10 Pro.

When browsing or if I select a specific .txt file it display the text in an illegible green colour font. Is it possible to change it to black?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Options -> Properties/Settings

Select "Editing" on the left

[image: Settings]

You will see your problem :)

Comment: Thanks. There's me expecting it to be under viewing or browsing!.